# _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability (20) once running on iPad Pro simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

When I launch app, I get the following error message:

> _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability (20)

What does the error message mean? What can I do about it?